# Spring Security redirects to wrong /login url in combination with Spring-Cloud-Gateway

Tags: spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I have 3 spring-boot services up and running.

- gateway-service -> localhost:8090
- eureka-service -> localhost:8091
- my-service (using Spring-Security + Web) -> localhost:8092

```
Gateway - application.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service  
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: my-service
        uri: lb://my-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/my-service/**
```

my-service has 2 endpoints
/info
/secured

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/secured").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

...
```

**localhost:8090/my-service/info** works fine.

**localhost:8090/my-service/secured** redirects to **localhost:8092/login**.

Is it possible to configure spring-security redirect to **localhost:8090/my-service/login** ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use X-Forwared-Headers with Spring Boot `ForwardedHeaderFilter`.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    ForwardedHeaderFilter filter = new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
    registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR);
    registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    registration.setUrlPatterns(List.of("/login", "/secured"));
    return registration;
}
```

I found it here.
https://tomgregory.com/spring-boot-behind-load-balancer-using-x-forwarded-headers/